# Switch CSS theming with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an HTML page with two buttons: a light theme button and a dark theme button. When I click the light theme button the background will turn light gray and text is black, when I click the dark theme button the background will turn black and text is white.

When I reopen my page the last theme selected should be generated.

so here is my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    </head>

    <div class="MyPage">
        <body>
            <h1>choose a theme:</h1>
            <input id="b1" type="button" value="light theme">
            <input id="b2" type="button" value="darck theme">
            <p>this a sample for using API local storage in HTML5 </p>        
        </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

css:

```
.MyLightPage 
{
    background-color: gray;
    text-decoration-color: black;
}
.MyDarkPage
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;  
}
```

My problem is how to connect the 3 diverse types of my project (HTML, CSS and JavaScript) and what functions should be existing in my JavaScript file to make this happen.

Comment: If you want to maintain the same theme as last visit you'll need to store a variable somewhere on the server, perhaps in a database.  You could set a cookie on the client machine or associate the setting with a particular login.

Comment: there is local storage in html 5 won't need to use a database

Comment: @Biffen You've been around long enough to know how to help out by making it better instead of complaining

Comment: @LGSon I made an attempt but couldn't come up with anything, perhaps I wasn't very motivated since it's *not my job*. Moreover, I think there's a point in pointing it out: Perhaps OP will learn something from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done using JavaScript.
The buttons call different functions where the background and text color is being set.

```css
#MyPage {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;  
}
```

```html
<div id="MyPage">
     <h1>choose a theme:</h1>
     <input id="b1" onclick="lightTheme()" type="button" value="light theme">
     <input id="b2" onclick="darkTheme()" type="button" value="dark theme">
     <p>this a sample for using API local storage in HTML5 </p>  
     <script>
        function darkTheme() {
            document.getElementById('MyPage').style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById('MyPage').style.color = "white";
          }

          function lightTheme() {
            document.getElementById('MyPage').style.backgroundColor = "white";
            document.getElementById('MyPage').style.color = "black";
          }
     </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet shows how to set the relevant CSS classes upon the click of a button. Saving the selecting theme can be added to the JS part easily - please refer to the very simple [Localstorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for details.

```js
$('#b1').click(function() {
  $('body').attr("class","MyLightPage");
});
$('#b2').click(function() {
  $('body').attr("class","MyDarkPage");
});
```

```css
.MyLightPage 
  {
     background-color: gray;
     text-decoration-color: black;

   }
 .MyDarkPage
     {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;  
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <div class="MyPage">

       <h1>choose a theme:</h1>
        <input id="b1" type="button" value="light theme">
        <input id="b2" type="button" value="dark theme">
        <p>this a sample for using API local storage in HTML5 </p>        
 </div>
</body>
```

As a side note, please also have a look at how a basic HTML document is structured. The `body` tag should not be the child of any `div`s, it has to be the direct child of the `html` tag.

Comment: it didn't work in my project so can you tell me what i've done wrong!!
this is my html's head:
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">        </script>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  </head>

Comment: You'll have to be a little more specific - please update your question with the code you have and the concrete issue you face.

Comment: can you please explain more to me because i don't know where to put the code of the click functions

i put the themes in a css file and the first snippet in a javascript file

Comment: After re-reading your question, the issue might be the order in which you load your scripts. If you're using jQuery in `index.js`, jQuery has to be included before `index.js`. Try swapping the two `script` tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the state of the last color that is clicked you need to hold some data on the server. The DOM will refresh every time you do a hard page reload. Database data, however, maintains the data that you can fetch on every page load. You can update this database data when one of the buttons is clicked. You have different ways to implement this. An example could be:

```
.theme-styling{
  <?php echo getDarkOrLightThemeCode(); ?>
}
```

Then in the DOM, you can assign theme styling to specific elements that have a light and dark element styling:

```
<button class="btn btn-large theme-styling">Hello</button>
<button class="btn btn-large theme-styling">Goodbye</button>
```

You can add an `id` to specific elements if you want additional styling apart from your dark and light theme styles.

And then specifically, when the user clicks a dark theme button or light theme button, you should create an AJAX request to update the variable property on the server.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var element = document.querySelector('body'),
    button  = document.querySelector('#myButton');

button.addEventListener('click',function(){

    if(element.className == 'MyLightPage'){

        element.className = 'MyDarkPage';

    }else{

        element.className = 'MyLightPage';

    }

});
```

Comment: i have to work on three files index.html ,index.css ,index.js so can you tell me what to put in each file please